# Koala Facebook error 500 when I use put_picture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

I'been trying to publish a photo in my ruby app using Koala Facebook. I read lots and lots of sites and posts but I couldn't reach the solution.
This is the code I have:

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(credentials.token)
albums = @graph.get_connections('me', 'albums') 
albuminfo = @graph.put_object('me','albums', :name=>'MyAppAlbum')
album_id = albuminfo["id"]

cover = @graph.put_picture(image_url)
cover_id = cover ["id]"
CoverSocialService.new(cover).upload_facebook_cover_picture(session[:fb_credentials], path_to_url(@cover.filtered_url))

redirect_to "https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?preview_cover=#{cover_id}"
```

This gives me the error:

```
Type: OAuthException, code: 1, message: An unknown error has occurred. [HTTP 500]
```

n line:

```
cover = @graph.put_picture(image_url)
```

I already tried with a different thread. I already checkd my permissions: photo_upload, publish_stream, user_photos.

The script creates MyAppAlbum correctly but I just cannot publish the photo.

Photo's size is lower than 700px x 700 px and 800kb

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

Check out that image_url is a valid, publicly accessible URL. I made that mistake...

Comment: Yes. It was accessible, but it was a goog guess. The problem was solved by other dev. But I didn't see how. thanks for the answer